# Diagnostic plot of gamma log link model in DHARMa package

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, diagnostic

I used this formula in Rstudio: `model<-glm (NRQ1~Sample, family= gamma (link= 'log'), data =df)` and to check the model, I used `simulateResiduals (fittedModel = model)` in DHARMa package. I got two figures saying quantile deviation detected (show below) but one is significant one is not in terms of combined adjusted quantile test.

[image]
[image]

I have tried to fit my data in Gaussian with either log link or identity link and Gamma with log link or inverse link, but none of them worked. I do not have other parameters that could be added into this model and also do not want to use transformation. Could someone tell me how to fix this problem? For the one says the test is not significant, is that okay if I leave it there?

I am very much appreciated your help!

Comment: What is `NRQ1`? What is the process creating this variable?

Comment: Hi, sorry it's my first time asking question here. I directly import my data from excel, NRQ1 is my dependent variable, e.g., 'ahrl<- c('1.074707', '1.000000', '1.082336', '1.070886', '1.034788', '1.840637', '1.896576', '1.558280', '1.764787', '1.932429', '1.824156', '1.960633','1.982936', '1.909764', '1.841959', '1.981795', '1.908183', '1.961721', '1.956090', '1.847025', '2.189630', '2.020699', '1.901727', '1.820731')'. Sample is my categorical variable (independent), 'Sample<- c('0', '3.125', '6.25','12.5','25')'. 'df<-data.frame(c('ahrl', 'Sample'))'. Then I did steps as described above.